# Is this NSScanner 's bug?

Tags: ios, ios5

The code snippet is as follows:

```
    unichar chars[] = {0x0030, 0x0031, 0x0032, 0x003B, 0x0E31};//the testString is "012;" plus a thai character
    NSString *testString = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:chars length:5];
    NSLog(@"testString %@", testString);
    NSScanner *theScanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:testString];
    NSString *result = nil;
    [theScanner scanUpToString:@";" intoString:&result];        
    //[theScanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";"]          intoString:&result];

    NSLog(@"the result is %@", result);
```

using scanUpToString failed, however, using scanUpToCharactersFromSet works. And if the character after 0x003B is not 0x0E31, for example ,0x0030, both api works.
So I guess scanUpToString has a bug dealing with some characters.
Does anyone has better ideas? 
Thank you.

Comment: Does this produce errors? Warnings? Console output?

Comment: If using scanUpTostring, the Console output of result is 012;ั   The result should be 012;